# vim :make :cwindow, I need error length character limit larger than 1000

Tags: gvim, quickfix, makeprg, hidden-buffers

I am compiling a program with :make command, then I examine g++ errors using :cwindow. The problem is that the error produced by g++ is longer than 1000 characters and it is cut.

Currently I have to compile this program in separate xterm in order to see complete error message which has 2403 characters length.

Comment: Just some suggestions which may not be nice solutions: a) change `makeprg` and pipe the output to a post processing script which gives better error messages for quick fix; b) instead of a separate xterm, I wonder if something like `:!` calling shell commands would make it easier to switch between vim and the error output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [7.4.1802](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1802), Vim is supposed to quickfix lines up to 4096 bytes long instead of truncating them.